# Extend nano menu

Tags: nano

Some hotkeys for `nano` are listed in the bottom depends on window scaling. How can I switch through this menu to see all the available hotkeys?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my experience, `nano` detects window sizes (and resizes) and scales the bottom bar accordingly, but the options remain the same. Can you show a screenshot of what exactly is happening with you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see all the `nano` shortcuts in a new buffer. If you want to come back to editing your file, you just need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> one time.